# Polymorphic associations and join syntax for defining scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to define a scope that references the attribute 'state' on my polymorphic association.

My real world problem is that I have articles and events that refer to specific items. I am capturing these as item_references. My articles and events can be in draft or published state. I would like to be able to extract item_references where the association (item_referenceable) state is published.

Something like this:

`scope :published_resource, -> { where("item_referenceable.published?") }`

but that obviously doesn't work because `item_referenceable` is an instance method and I'm working at the class level. I suspect I need to go down the join front but I'm struggling to see how.

Here are the relevant bits of my code:

Models:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_references, as: :item_referenceable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_references, allow_destroy: true,
   :reject_if => proc { |att| att[:item_unique_id].blank? }
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_references, as: :item_referenceable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_references, allow_destroy: true,
   :reject_if => proc { |att| att[:item_unique_id].blank? }
end

class ItemReference < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item_referenceable, polymorphic: true

  scope :in_articles, -> { where("item_referenceable_type = 'Article'") }
end
```

Schema Extracts:

```
create_table "events", id do |t|
t.string "title"
t.datetime "start_date_time"
t.datetime "end_date_time"
t.string "state"

create_table "article", id do |t|
t.string "title"
t.string "slug"
t.text "body"
t.string "state"

create_table "item_references", id do |t|
t.text "item_unique_reference"
t.string "item_referenceable_type"
t.bigint "item_referenceable_id"
t.index ["item_referenceable_type", "item_referenceable_id"], name: "idx_item_refs"
```

The problem is likely to expand as I will ultimately be referring to items across multiple models eg courses, blogs etc. I'm wondering if it would be possible to define the scope without having to specify specific model names and use the item_referenceable_type to refer to the model name.

Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

`scope :published_resource, -> { joins(:item_referenceable_type).where('item_references.item_referenceable.published?') }`

I am ultimately trying to generate an API that shows by item_unique_id all the Articles and Events that refer to that item.

Like this:

```
{
 "title": "Retrieve all item references",
 "items": [
   {
     "item_unique_id": "O12",
     "articles": [
       {
         "resource_id": 1,
         "title": "Penguin",
         "state": "published",
         "slug": "test-article"
       }
      ],
     "events": []
   },
```

I've got to the above stage using `ItemReference.all.group_by(&:item_unique_id)` but that retrieves all resources (Events/Articles) whether they are published or not.

Comment: I'm afraid I am still a bit unclear. First where is state and what datatype is state ? Is it stored in `Article` and `Event` separately or is it stored in `ItemReference`. Second what is the end goal here, to be able to call `ItemReferences.published_resources`?

Comment: Ah sorry that is not clear. There is an attribute state on the models Event and Article. I can call published? on all instances which return true if state == 'Published'. And yes that is exactly what I want to do. I am trying to prepare an API that shows all articles and Events that refer to specific Items and I only want to show published Articles and Events so `ItemReferences.published_resources`

Comment: Okay. Well a polymorphic association is not going to necessarily allow you to call `ItemReferences.published_resources` and get back both `Event` and `Article` objects but each item independently can perform that on its own e.g. `scope :published { where(state: 'Published') }` if placed in `Article` will allow you to call `Article.published`

Comment: I can already call Article.published or Event.published but the problem is that my API needs to return all relevant resources by item. I'll edit my question to try and make it a bit clearer. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Yeah as I was mentioning polymorphic associations cannot do that due to the nature of the join. If you try for yourself you will see the following error `ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError: Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :item_referenceable`. What I would recommend is building a separate class for this functionality and querying each independently. This is something I could provide an example for.

Comment: Oh dear.... I've just added clarification in my post if it helps but it sounds like I may have chosen the wrong way to model the relationship. I'd be happy to see your example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would recommend handling this: (in shorthand as extended functionality will almost definitely be a requirements)

```
class Publishable 
   PUBLISHABLES = {articles: Article, events: Event}
   attr_reader :results
   attr_accessor :limit, :conditions   
   def initialize(conditions={})
      @conditions = conditions 
      @results = {} 
   end   

   def as_json(options={})
     fetch if results.empty?  
     results.as_json(options) 
   end  

   def published!
     conditions.merge!({stage: 'Published'})
     self 
   end 

   private 
     def fetch
       PUBLISHABLES.each do |node, klass| 
         results[node] = klass.where(conditions).limit(limit)
       end  
     end 
end
```

Then you can simply call

```
publishables = Publishable.new
publishables.published!
publishables.limit = 10 
publishables.results
```

As I mentioned this is extremely over simplified just to give you an example and I would certainly consider expanding upon this functionality but hopefully it helps point you in a direction